# Pandas giving MemoryError()

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, numpy

I have the one dataframe of 1140566 rows x 146 columns, where I read the large csv with option low_memory = False

But once I tried to select any column values there or trying to run df.info(memory_usages ='deep') it gives me MemoryError, I have 32 G free Ram and file is less than 1 GB, I am using pandas 0.18 I tried the 0.23 have similar issues.

Any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: welcome to community , before asking you should use good search engine and query if there exists answer, else you should post here .Reinventing the wheel consume time.

Comment: Thanks I got this resolved switching to 64 bit python interpreter.